# How to run a single test script on two different machines using Selenium grid? On both machines the test script should run on IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have configured a node and two different nodes. The both node machine runs on windows and  only IE. So i want to run my test script on these two nodes at the same time(parallely). But when i am trying this scripts are running one after another not simultaneously. please find below my code.

```html
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role hub -port 8080
```

```html
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://172.29.70.143:8080/grid/register - browser "browserName=ie,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS" -port 8080
```

```html
public class Sample {

 WebDriver driver;
 String baseUrl, nodeUrl;

 @BeforeTest
 public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
  baseUrl = "https://10.87.137.219/selfRegistration_sit/";
  nodeUrl = "http://172.29.70.143:8080/wd/hub";
  DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  capability
    .setCapability(
      InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
      true);
  capability.setBrowserName("ie");
  capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
  
      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capability);
  
  capability
    .setCapability(
      InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
      true);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }


 @Test
 public void test() throws Exception {
  driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
  driver.navigate().to(
    "javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
 
//  System.out.println("Certifi");
//  System.out.println("After certifi");

  // click on register Non VIL
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_img_reg")).click();
  // enter supervisor name
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmployeeID"))
    .sendKeys("90001451");
  // click on search
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$IbtnGetDetTab3"))
    .click();

  Thread.sleep(2000);
  // //click on select
  List<WebElement> List=driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'javascript:__doPostBack(')]"));
  List.get(1).click();
    

  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName"))
    .sendKeys("Mani");
  // select circle
  new Select(driver.findElement(By
    .name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drpCircle")))
    .selectByVisibleText("GUJARAT");
  // location
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtLocation"))
    .sendKeys("Location");
  // departmenr
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDept"))
    .sendKeys("Department");
  // mobilenumber
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtMobile"))
    .sendKeys("8983152157");
  // sub departmnet
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSubdept"))
    .sendKeys("Sub Department");
  // email
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtOwnerEamil"))
    .sendKeys("Email");
  // domain
  new Select(driver.findElement(By
    .name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drpmailids")))
    .selectByVisibleText("VODA.COM");
  // designation
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDesignation"))
    .sendKeys("Designation");
  // org name
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtVendorname"))
    .sendKeys("Organistaion");
  // POI type
  new Select(driver.findElement(By
    .name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlPOI_TYPE")))
    .selectByVisibleText("PAN Card");
  // POI value
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPOI_Value"))
    .sendKeys("PAN123413");
  // //physical
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbAccess_0"))
    .click();
  // vf user
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbEmpVf_1"))
    .click();
  // click on proceed
  driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$IbtnSubmit"))
    .click();

 
 }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

   <test name="IETest">
   <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
      <classes>
         <class name="testScripts.Sample" />
      </classes>
   </test>
   
</suite>
```

Comment: I think you did not set NODE pcs , Did you? , you have to set PCs as node in which you want to run tests from HUB machine.

Comment: yes i have set up a hub and two nodes. the script is running on both the nodes but not simultaneously I want the script to run at a time on both the nodes.

Comment: Please check this : https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf  - Go to page no. 14 , that will help you I think.                Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @HelpingHands . In this document they have provided parallel tests for cross browser and cross platform , but my two nodes runs on same platform and same browser. How can we achieve parallel execution for this scenario. Any inputs ??

Comment: Means you do not have diff. 3 machines? 1 - hub , 2 - node1 , 3 - node2 ??

Comment: No i have 3 different machines, 1 - hub , 2-node1 and 3-node2 . When i say same platform and same browser i actually meant all the machines run on Windows 7 and all the machines use IE.

Comment: ok then it should work. I am not getting any fault in your code. do you getting any error?

Comment: No i am not getting any error but only script is executing on only one machine at a time. After the completion of one test on Node1 then execution is starting on Node2. And node1 is the node which is connected first to the hub.

Answer (score -1):

You have parallel="tests" in your testng xml configuration file and it has only one test tag in it. Have multiple tests tags pointing to single test method in code to run parallel tests or change parallel="tests" to parallel="methods" and keep at least two methods in your class so that it will run two test methods in parallel.

Comment: Thanks pratik, Actually i want to run the same method on both the nodes parallely. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: You just add below code in testng config xml file and keep parallel="tests". <test name="IETest2">
   <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
      <classes>
         <class name="testScripts.Sample" />
      </classes>
   </test>